# How to convert real path CString c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a real windows path:

```
CString path = "C:\Programs File (x86)\Program folder\exec.exe";
```

How can I convert it to

```
CString path = "C:\\Programs File (x86)\\Program folder\\exec.exe";
```

I tried it with `path.Replace(L"\\", L"\\\\");` but it failed.

Comment: Under windows, the forward-slash is also a valid path separator. In this case, there is the advantage that the fixed-string is the same length as the broken one.

Comment: What do you mean it failed? I ask because `Programs File (x86)` is spelled incorrectly, it should be `Program Files (x86)`. This could just be a typo in the question though...

Comment: What do you mean by it failed? Did you get a compilation error? (because your inconsistent usage of the `L` prefix looks problematic.) Or did you try print out the result of the replace and it didn't look the way you wanted it to? (because that might be hiding backslashes.) i.e. Clarify your question - it is incomplete.

Comment: I'd encourage you to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so you can get better help.

Comment: From one of your comments I uderstood that your path is read from the registry. If the path is _actually_ `C:\Programs File (x86)\Program folder\exec.exe`, then you don't need to convert anything. The path is already valid. The double `\\\` is only needed of you are using a string literal.

Comment: @enh: The path separator on Windows is a backslash. Not all API calls will convert forward slashes to backslashes.

Comment: Hmm I've rarely seen so many poor and downvoted answers for a poorly asked question...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchcombineex

Answer (score 1):

In one of your comments you write that your path is read from the registry.

If the path is actually `C:\Programs File (x86)\Program folder\exec.exe`, then you don't need to convert anything. The path is already valid.

The double `\\` is only needed of you are using a string literal.

**Examples:**

Let's suppose your registry value contains `C:\Programs File (x86)\Program folder\exec.exe` verbatim

Program snippet 1:

```
CString somepath = YourGetFromRegistryFunction();
// now somepath contains the correct path already

AfxMessageBox(somepath);  // show the path for debugging purposes
```

Program snippet 2:

```
CString somepath = "C:\\Programs File (x86)\\Program folder\\exec.exe";
// now somepath contains the correct path already, the compiler
// replaces the `\\` with a single `\\`

AfxMessageBox(somepath);  // show the path for debugging purposes
```